# Link a PDF to open in a new tab FROM A PDF

Tags: pdf

I know this is not a specifically programming question but it is blowing my mind.

I need to do what the title says. I've tried lot of things are none of them are working (at least not cross browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, there's a relatively new PDF-AcroForm JS command that might do the trick:

```
app.launchURL(myURL, true);
```

That's a request for a *new window* not a new tab, but some browsers will interpret it as a new tab anyway.  This may be what you're alluding to with the "cross browser" comment.

The alternative is kinda icky.  There's a way to communicate between a web page and a PDF.

In the PDF, you set the documents "HostContainer" property to be an object with various methods:

In The PDF:

```
this.hostContainer.postMessage([theURL]);
```

In the HTML:

```
var thePDF = document.getElementById("thePDFObjectTagId");
thePDF.messageHandler = {
  onMessage: function(paramArray) {
    openANewTabWithTheUrl(paramArray[0]);
  }
}
```

The web page wrapping the PDF could be little more than an object tag and some script.

There's a mechanism for sending messages the other way too.  It's all defined in the [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf).  Look for the specs on "Embedded PDF" and "HostContainer".

Comment: The problem with launchURL is that if you are not using your default browser it will open your  URL in other browser, not even other window (the default one). It is really uggly. However the rest of your answer helped me to make it. Thanks!